# Spinnaker Pipeline is failing after starting it manually

Tags: config, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

## Spinnaker on Gke :

#### Pipeline is getting failed after starting manually

the first issue is the .spin/config didnt get created, I created that manually as missing in the steps https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-kubernetes-engine
then when i started pipeline manually , it is giving me an error on production stage

> > > Exception ( Wait For Manifest To Stabilize )
> > >       WaitForManifestStableTask of stage Deploy Production Backend timed out after 30 minutes 4 seconds. pausedDuration: 0 seconds, elapsedTime: 30 minutes 4 seconds,timeoutValue: 30 minutes

Comment: Has your issue  been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Many times this is caused by Kubernetes being unable to schedule the pods. Just had the same problem this morning and it was due to lack of resources. That would be the first thing I'd check. You can find the pod in the "Server Group" under the "Infrastructure" tab and view the details of why it's in the state it is.

Comment: Hi John 
I didnt find any server Group under that, Is it config related issue ? when i installed the spin cli the .spin/config didnt get created which i created manually , Could be this issue ?

Comment: Normally if it’s a spinnaker config issue it will fail out immediately. Verify it’s able to talk to the Kubernetes api as a network timeout could cause it. I’d check the clouddriver service’s logs and see what it says. You may have to turn debug logs on to get to the bottom of it, but it should give some insight into what it’s unable to talk to.

Comment: That was the resource crunch issue , Got resolved , Thanks a lot

Comment: there is another issue which is .spin/config didnt got created which i was talking earlier , means now pipeline ran successfully but there was nothing i got no servers group no ingress ips and all , while i was creating the application and pipeline through cloud shell it gave me an error " could not read configuration from .spin/config "  .. I tried creating manually using 1 link i got but i am not sure about the details like keys and certificates . this is the link : https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/spin/     Can you suggest something ?

Comment: `$ ./spin application save --application-name sample --owner-email example@example.com --cloud-providers kubernetes --gate-endpoint http://localhost:8080/gate
Could not read configuration file from /home/vidyasawanny/.spin/config.
Application save succeeded`

Comment: `$ export PROJECT=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
$sed s/PROJECT/$PROJECT/g /home/vidyasawanny/sample-app/spinnaker/pipeline-deploy.json > pipeline.json
$ ./spin pipeline save --gate-endpoint http://localhost:8080/gate -f pipeline.json
Could not read configuration file from /home/vidyasawanny/.spin/config.`

Pipeline save succeeded
`

Comment: That would depend on where you have it saving state too. Our instance saves it to a google storage bucket. If spinnaker is running in a container it may be saving it to disk in there. I don't think the CLI saves the file I think it's one of the Spinnaker services that persists it although I'm not sure which one.

Comment: its the bucket , i have followed this "https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-kubernetes-engine"  , i tried creating the config but it didnt work and nothign is mentioned in the official docs , if there is some manual thing to get created it should be mentioned in the docs as well , but it should get createdand worked but pipelines only gets created , they are not able to read configuration to run well

Answer (score 0):

I find this [Spinnaker GitHub](https://github.com/spinnaker/spin/pull/153) page insightful. I wanted to add it as a comment because I still don't have enough reputation.